# How to download a table from Microsoft SQL Server via Linux commandline?

Tags: sql-server

I can connect to SQL Server via command-line in Ubuntu? I have a table, let's say `my_table` in database `my_db` in a remote Microsoft SQL Server. Is there way to download `my_table` to my local linux OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`freebcp`](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/usefreetds.htm). Works just like [`bcp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Comment: I am getting this error "Cannot bcp with TDSVER < 5.0"